# How to add new line in Table onclick buton? LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-button

HTML :

```
<template>

<div class="slds-var-m-top_large slds-var-p-right_medium">
    <lightning-layout horizontal-align="left" vertical-align="end">
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Criteria__c">
            <lightning-layout-item size="5">
                <lightning-combobox 
                name="List Of Fields" 
                label="List Of Fields"
                placeholder="List Of Fields" 
                value={value} 
                onchange={handleChange} 
                options={Options}>
                </lightning-combobox>
                    <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Operator__c"></lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Value__c"></lightning-input-field>
<lightning-button type="submit" name="submit" label="Appliquer Filtre"></lightning-button>
<lightning-button label="Add new line" onclick={addFilter}></lightning-button>

    </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
            </lightning-layout>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just add a `for:each`, `for:item`, and `key` at the appropriate level. For example, you might do this:

```
<lightning-layout horizontal-align="left" vertical-align="end" for:each={filters} for:item="filter" key="filter.index">
```

And then in your controller:

```
@track filters = [{ index: 1 }];
#nextIndex = 2;
```

...

```
addFilter() {
  this.filters.push({ index: this.#nextIndex });
  this.#nextIndex = this.#nextIndex + 1;
}
```

Since you're using `lightning-record-edit-form`, you would have to submit each form individually. I recommend that you don't create a list of `lightning-record-edit-form`, as it is not designed to be used in bulk.

You can just use normal input fields, and then save the data with an Apex method.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox , in order to hide it once other buton is clicked ,  should i use **<template if:true** ? And how can i use normal input fields without using `lightning-record-edit-form` ?

Comment: Another note , i have puted `@track filters = [{ index: **0** }];
#nextIndex = **0**;` but it sill increment .. the field is showing once i click on buton ..

Comment: @Fabien (a) just use lightning-select/lightning-input/lightning-combobox as you need. You can use getPicklistValues to get the values for the `Operator__c` field. Also, each `key` needs to be unique. I chose 1 and 2, you could choose 0 and 1. Just make sure the keys are unique.

Comment: do you know how to display filters using the index? i have created an apex method which retrieve filters but i'm blocked on how to display them on the layout with index 1 if there's 1 record , index 2 if theres 2 ..

Comment: @Fabien I don't know what you want, so I wrote a little [demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/VZgYTjQnBfHGVHILp0Uk/src/app.js?p=stories) for you.

Comment: Thanks any way for your demo man !!! i wanted to use it but i couldn't since you use a static fields , this method wont work in my side  :  `wire(getCriterias, {  listview: '$listViewId' })
            handleGetFilters(response) {
                const { data } = response;
                this.filters0 = data.map((filter, index0)=>({...filter, index0}));
                console.log('*//////////////', this.filters0);
              //  this.cleanUp();
            }`

But thanks a lot again

Comment: can you share the apex method? i'm blocked here , nthg works ..

Comment: what's **filter, index** ? why you map them?

Comment: nthg works.....

Comment: @Fabien See MDN on [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to understand `() => ({})` syntax, and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Also , **event.target.closest('div[data-index]').dataset.index**  doesnt work

Comment: can we have a discussion for 10min plz?

Comment: @Fabien I set up a [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139036/how-to-duplicate-form-using-foreach-onclick-buton-lwc), I'll be there for the next hour or so before I have to get ready for the day. Otherwise, we can try to connect later today, but my days are pretty busy.

Comment: do you know how to get the id of removed cell from table : `removeRow(event) {
            this.caseDefaultData.splice(event.target.dataset.index, 1);
            this.caseDefaultData = this.caseDefaultData.map((x, index)=>({...x, index, rowNumber: index+1}));`  i want to get the *ids* of removed cells ..